# Clearing Timeout on hover jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having some trouble with clearing the timeout set on showing the tooltip. I believe I understand how it works, but for some reason it doesn't work here.

```
$('.div').hover(
    function(){ var t = setTimeout(function() {
                $('.tooltip').show(500);
                }, 500);},
    function(){ clearTimeout(t);
                $('.tooltip').hide(300);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move variable declaration outside the function to get the variable scope in both callbacks otherwise `t` can't access within the second callback. Although use [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) method if you want to stop currently running animation.

```
var t;
$('.div').hover(function() {
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.tooltip').show(500);
  }, 500);
}, function() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  $('.tooltip').stop().hide(300);
});
```

---

Or use [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay) method to provide a delay between animation queue.

```
$('.div').hover(function() {
  $('.tooltip').delay(500).show(500);
}, function() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  $('.tooltip').stop().hide(300);
});
```